# Merge two files with different header value

Tags: file, vbscript, merge

I need to merge 2 files into a new file using .vbs. Both files contains header and data. For header, I need to sum both files row count & also the total amount. For the data, I need to merge both data from these two files.

Header format:

```
yyyymmdd|FILENAME|row count|total amount
```

Sample of files & format as below:

**File 1:**

```
20160204|FILENAME|3|17
20160204|SARAH|OWEN|SCIENCE BOOK|20090717|USD|2|SCIENCE|0|
20160204|KYLE|PARKER|ENGLISH BOOK|20090717|USD|10|ENGLISH|0|
20160204|LILY|MORGAN|POLITICAL BOOK|20090717|USD|5|POLITICS|0|
```

**File 2:**

```
20160204|FILENAME|1|4
20160204|ADAM|HANSEL|HISTORY BOOK|20090717|USD|4|HISTORY|0|
```

**Output:**

```
20160204|FILENAME|4|21
20160204|SARAH|OWEN|SCIENCE BOOK|20090717|USD|2|SCIENCE|0|
20160204|KYLE|PARKER|ENGLISH BOOK|20090717|USD|10|ENGLISH|0|
20160204|LILY|MORGAN|POLITICAL BOOK|20090717|USD|5|POLITICS|0|
20160204|ADAM|HANSEL|HISTORY BOOK|20090717|USD|4|HISTORY|0|
```

I only managed to merge the two files. But it is not the output I want.

So far I only have this:

```
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objOutputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("MYFILE.txt")

Set objTextFile   = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\Testing\MYFILE1.txt", ForReading)
strText = objTextFile.ReadAll
objTextFile.Close

objOutputFile.WriteLine strText

Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\Testing\MYFILE2.txt", ForReading)
strText = objTextFile.ReadAll
objTextFile.Close

objOutputFile.WriteLine strText

objOutputFile.Close
```

Comment: A header is a line with **column names**. Not what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is:

- read the data rows of the two files
- extract the 7th field of each data row
- calculate the sum of all extracted values
- write the new header with sum and total number of data rows
- write all data rows to the file

For small-ish files one way would be something like this:

```
datafiles = Array("D:\Testing\MYFILE1.txt", "D:\Testing\MYFILE2.txt")

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim header
ReDim data(-1)

sum = 0
For Each filename In datafiles
  Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)
  header = Split(f.ReadLine, "|")
  Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
    ReDim Preserve data(UBound(data)+1)
    line = f.ReadLine
    data(UBound(data)) = line
    sum = sum + CInt(Split(line, "|")(6))
  Loop
  f.Close
Next

Set f = fso.CreateTextFile("MYFILE.txt")
f.WriteLine header(0) & "|" & header(1) & "|" & (UBound(data)+1) & "|" & sum
For Each row In data
  f.WriteLine row
Next
f.Close
```

Beware that this won't perform too well for large files, though. If you need to process files like that you'll have to handle them differently (writing the data rows line by line to a temporary file instead of keeping them in memory, then writing header and merged data to the final file line by line in a second step).

Answer (score -2):

Hope this helps:

```
<%
Class contFiles
  Public Files

  Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set Files = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  End Sub

  Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    If IsObject(Files) Then
      Files.RemoveAll()
      Set Files = Nothing
    End If
  End Sub

  Public Sub addFile(theFileName)
    Files.Add theFileName, theFileName
  End Sub

  Public Default Function makeFile(fileName)
    On Error Resume Next

    theKeys = Files.Keys
    Set FSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Do Until IDx = Files.Count
      Set TheTextStream = FSO.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath(theKeys(IDx)), 1)
      html = html & TheTextStream.ReadAll
      IDx = IDx + 1
    Loop

    Set objTxt = FSo.CreateTextFile(Server.MapPath(fileName), True, False)
    objTxt.Write(html)
    objTxt.Close

    If ( err.Number <> 0 ) Then
      makeFile = False
    Else
      makeFile = True
    End If
  End Function
End Class

Set testFiles = New contFiles

testFiles.addFile("default.aspx")
testFiles.addFile("events.aspx")
testFiles.addFile("about.aspx")

response.write(testFiles.makeFile("test.txt"))
%>
```

Comment: How it's helpful to OP?

Comment: It isn't. It doesn't do anything beyond the mere file concatenation that the OP already has working. Plus, it's ASP, not standalone VBScript like the OP is using.

Comment: What is this all about? My eyes!!